# Limit Properties

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I know that if $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)=l \implies \lim_{x \to a} |f|(x)=|l|$.

If we know that  $\lim_{x \to a} |f|(x)=|l|$ then what can we say about $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ ?

Are there any implications? If so then what are they? Is the implication that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)=l$ or $-l$ true or false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In general, we cannot conclude from $\lim_{x\to a} |f(x)|=l$ that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ even exists.**
(See the answer of haqnatural)

However, there are still some implications.

> **First case: $\lim f(x)$ exists**

Assume that $\lim f(x)$ exists.
The absolute value is a continuous function. Hence the limit operation can be exchanged with taking the absolut value. We get

$$ |\lim_{x\to a} f(x)|=\lim_{x\to a}|f(x)|$$

Thus if the limit $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ exists, then the limit $\lim_{x\to a} |f(x)|$ is $+\lim f(x)$ or $-\lim f(x)$.

> **Second case: $\lim |f(x)|=0$**

It is always true that 
$-|f(x)|\le f(x) \le |f(x)|$. Hence the limit of this equation implies

$$0=-\lim_{x\to a}|f(x)|\le \liminf_{x\to a}f(x) \le\limsup_{x\to a}f(x) \le \lim_{x\to a}|f(x)|=0.$$
Thus $\liminf_{x\to a}f(x) =\limsup_{x\to a}f(x)=0$, which implies $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=0$.

Comment: So if $lim|f(x)|=0$ then $limf(x)$ exists and it is equal to $0$ ?

Comment: Yes, if $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ coincide, then the limit exists and has the same value.

Answer (score 0):

As Counter example take $$\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \left| { \left( -1 \right)  }^{ n } \right|  } =1$$ however  $$\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ { \left( -1 \right)  }^{ n } } $$ limit not exsist

Answer (score 0):

Nothing can be concluded from $\lim\limits_{x \to a} |f|(x)=|l|$.  Consider the function
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
l &\text{if } x \in \Bbb Q \\
-l &\text{if } x \in \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q.
\end{cases}
$$

$|f| \equiv l$ is continuous everywhere on $\Bbb R$. (In particular, at $a \in \Bbb R$, $\lim\limits_{x \to a} |f|(x)$ exists and is equal to $|l|$.)  However, due to the density of (ir)rational numbers in $\Bbb R$, $f$ is discontinuous everywhere, so the limit $\lim\limits_{x \to a} |f|(x)$ doesn't exist for any $a \in \Bbb R$.

Hence the limit of $|f(x)|$ at $a \in \Bbb R$ doesn't imply that of $f(x)$ at $a$.